# Unable to the get the gallery inserted between shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I am customizing this theme . I am using `get_the_gallery()` function to get the gallery from the custom post . I am able to do so, but when the gallery is inserted between the shortcodes...

For eg:

```
[two-third]

[gallery ids="18,17,8,7,6"]

[/two-third]
```

then i am not able to get the gallery..I am using the following code

```
<?php                  
    if ( get_post_gallery() ):     
       $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
       $w3_ids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );               
?>                 

<?php  
    $gallery_count=1;
    foreach( $w3_ids AS $w3_id ): 
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($w3_id,'full'); 
?>  
    <div class="item <?php if($gallery_count==1)echo "active"; ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
<?php 
    $gallery_count++;
    endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

What can be done... Please help

Comment: Maybe the add_shortcode for two-third container is not returning a value within do_shortcode() again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the code is not working.
But this is how i did this may be helpful for some noob like me

```
<?php                  
    $name = get_the_content();          
    preg_match('/\[gallery ids="([^]]*)\"]/', $name, $match);                  
    $w3_ids = explode( ",", $match[1] ); 
    $gallery_count=1;
    foreach( $w3_ids AS $w3_id ): 
       $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($w3_id,'full'); 
?>  
    <div class="item <?php if($gallery_count==1)echo "active"; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
<?php 
    $gallery_count++;
    endforeach;        
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $id=the_ID();
    $gallery_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' && ID=$id");
    echo $gallery_count;
?>
```

I think...!!! Try this for Particular gallery.

Comment: what would be $id

Comment: Please explain why this will solve the issue. Don't just dump code and tell someone to try it. Explain how your code works and how it should be used